# Struggle with typing redux-form component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form

I am trying to export my component A by decorating it with redux-form in order to have access on my form-state, which is mainly filled by another component.

When trying to export my component, I get this typing-error:

```
TS2322 Type A is not assignable to type B
```

```
(Property 'onAbortHandler' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<FormInstance<{}.......)
```

I also tried to connect my Component and then to decorate my connected Component with reduxForm. Thats also not working.

This is my code

```
interface OwnProps {
  onAbortHandler: () => void;
  onSubmitHandler: () => void;
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component
    <OwnProps & Partial<InjectedFormProps>>  {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Button
              className={'btn}
              onClick={this.props.onAbortHandler}
          >
            <FormattedMessage id={'xx'}/>
          </Button>
          <Button
              className={'btn'}
              type="submit"
              onClick={this.props.onSubmitHandler}
          >
            <FormattedMessage id={'xx'}/>
          </Button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'myFormName',
})(MyComponent);
```

Where is my mistake and why does this seem to be not straight forward?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
interface OwnProps {
  onAbortHandler: () => void;
  onSubmitHandler: () => void;
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component
    <OwnProps & InjectedFormProps<{}, OwnProps>>  {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Button
              className={'btn}
              onClick={this.props.onAbortHandler}
          >
            <FormattedMessage id={'xx'}/>
          </Button>
          <Button
              className={'btn'}
              type="submit"
              onClick={this.props.onSubmitHandler}
          >
            <FormattedMessage id={'xx'}/>
          </Button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm<{}, OwnProps>({
  form: 'myFormName',
}
```

`InjectedProps` contains `handleSubmit` method that should know about the props you will pass to form. Check [library types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7c77a9c53a5d3e3c3c0a29a466b5acf810cac7a4/types/redux-form/v7/lib/reduxForm.d.ts#L84) here for more info.